# Nextjs 13 multiple Facebook pixels with Link

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, facebook-pixel

Imagine the following stack of routes in my site. I need to setup my own pixel ID all over the pages, all of them. Till here it's everything ok, but I need to add a customer pixel ID only on the Event and deeper pages. I mean, on the home page we have a list of Events and each one can have a different pixel ID, but it need it to be cleaned when the user go back to the root pages.

It works using the regular link tag , but I couldn't find a way to do that using the  component

```
Home
 |--Event
      |--Payment
About
Login
Register
```